# Error parsing www/config.xml: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Do you know how I can solve this problem? I am new to Ionic. For the reference I am using [version 1 of this app](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201511161733844/social-network-with-firebase-social-network-starter-with-firebase-auth-and-ngcordova) from Ionic Market Place.

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:social_network mona$ ls
bower.json      hooks           node_modules        plugins         www
config.xml      ionic.config.json   package.json        resources
gulpfile.js     ionic.project       platforms       scss
Monas-MacBook-Pro:social_network mona$ ionic serve

Error parsing www/config.xml: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/utils.js:243:47
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:484:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Object.onclosetag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:445:26)
    at emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:640:35)
    at emitNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:645:5)
    at closeTag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:905:7)
    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1449:13)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:503:31) (CLI v2.0.0-beta.32)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.2.0

Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v5.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 6.2 Build version 6C131e 



Monas-MacBook-Pro:social_network mona$ cordova telemetry on
Thanks for opting into telemetry to help us improve cordova.
Monas-MacBook-Pro:social_network mona$ ionic serve

Error parsing www/config.xml: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/utils.js:243:47
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:484:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Object.onclosetag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:445:26)
    at emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:640:35)
    at emitNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:645:5)
    at closeTag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:905:7)
    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1449:13)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:503:31) (CLI v2.0.0-beta.32)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v5.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 6.2 Build version 6C131e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing config.xml in www folder:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:social_network mona$ cd www
Monas-MacBook-Pro:www mona$ ls
config      css     img     index.html  js      lib     templates
```

Also mentioned [here](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201511161733844/social-network-with-firebase-social-network-starter-with-firebase-auth-and-ngcordova), apparently it's a Phonegap build issue.